# offset is undefined in Header Fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

I now have a code to fixed the header of my tables and it works fine. But this function have a warning :

```
Error: TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined
```

My code (I use bootstrap):

```
function goheadfixed(classtable) {
$(classtable).wrap('<div class="fix-inner">'); 
$('.fix-inner').wrap('<div class="fix-outer" style="position: relative;"></div>'); //this is relative cause the header will be absolute
$('.fix-outer').append('<div class="fix-head"></div>');
$('.fix-head').prepend($('.fix-inner').html()); // agrego la tabla
$('.fix-head table').find('caption').remove();
//$('.fix-head table').removeAttr('style');
$('.fix-head table').css('width','100%');

$('.fix-head').css('width', $('.fix-inner table').outerWidth(true)+'px');
$('.fix-head').css('height', $('.fix-inner table thead').outerHeight(true)+'px');

var ithead = parseInt($('.fix-inner table thead').offset().top);
var divfix = parseInt($('.fix-inner').offset().top);
var itop = ithead-divfix;

$('.fix-head').css({'position':'absolute', 'overflow':'hidden', 'top': itop+'px', 'left':0, 'z-index':100 });

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var vscroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(vscroll >= ithead)
        $('.fix-head').css('top',(vscroll-divfix)+'px');
    else
        $('.fix-head').css('top', itop+'px');
});

/*  If the windows resize   */
$(window).resize(goresize);
}

function goresize() {
$('.fix-head').css('width', $('.fix-inner table').outerWidth(true)+'px');
$('.fix-head').css('height', $('.fix-inner table thead').outerHeight(true)+'px');
}
```

I call my function:

```
goheadfixed('table.fixed');
```

Then when I put other code javascript below, my code doesn't work but when put above, it works fine! :

How can I delete this warninng?

**EDIT (adding details posted as an answer)**: 
Oh. I'm sorry, I forgot say the "warning" only appears when I don't use the function.

If I call the funcion goheadfixed('table.fixed'); all right, but if I don't call this function, the warning is showed.

Comment: What line is causing the error (will be listed in the console)?

Comment: The error is line 14. var ithead = parseInt($('.fix-inner table thead').offset().top);

Comment: I forgot. When I call the function, all right!. But when I don't use this funcion, show these warning "Error: TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined"

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry, I forgot say the "warning" only appears when I don't use the function. If I call the funcion goheadfixed('table.fixed'); all right, but if I don't call this function, the warning is showed.

Answer (score 0):

On line 14, `$('.fix-inner table thead')` is either referring to elements that do not exist or are hidden. It sounds as if you are finding at least one element with `display:none` set, and it's returning an undefined number because of that.

To fix this, you can add the visible selector `$("thead:visible")` with each element.

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry, I forgot say the "warning" only appears when I don't use the function.

Comment: Then what exactly is the question? If your code is throwing an error, no code beyond the line error should process.